# Should the QGIS "DB Manager" have Microsoft SQL Server as an option?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I was looking for interactive query options for SQL Server (similar to SQL Server Management Studio). The "DB Manager" works great for Postgres and I'm primarily using the `Load as new layer` as I build out spatial queries. I would love to be able to do the same thing with SQL Server. Currently, I'll make a view and access that view via the `Add MSSQL Spatial Layer...`, that's a lot of flipping back and forth.

But I'm fairly inexperienced with QGIS, so I'd like to confirm that I am seeing what I should be seeing and that I'm not missing a configuration item?
[image]

If what I am seeing is correct, are there any GIS plug-ins out there that approximate this functionality?  My searches have been unsuccessful so far (*searching for SQL and Server returns a lot of irrelevant results!*) and the Plugin search brings back a lot of results for Postgres:

[image]

`QGIS version: 2.12.1-Lyon    QGIS code revision: 16760fd`

Comment: Do you mean 'should it be there and i'm not seeing it' ,or 'i think it should be there, what do you all think'?

Comment: The former...wanted to make sure I didn't have QGIS misconfigured and if not, are there plugin options.

Comment: I've never seen it, so I think what you're looking at is correct... I haven't seen any plugins for MSSQL...

Comment: In this irc log: http://irclogs.geoapt.com/qgis/%23qgis.2014-09-06.log (search for `17:01:39` ) There's a chat about MSSQL and DBManager (confirming that it doesn't support MSSQL).  Any idea what: "use the browser (widget)" means?

Comment: Maybe just the 'browser panel' interface for MSSQL in QGIS?

Comment: Is this still the case for QGIS 3.x? in 2020 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not supported (yet). Db manager only supports Postgres, Spatialite and Oracle databases.

Comment: Is this still the case for QGIS 3.x?

Comment: Yes, still the case